I can't compile Whisper Ai into EXE file with Pyinstaller
i'm not sure if its a ffmpeg issue or a whisper ai issue
but after compiling my .py file with pyinstaller into one exe file using this command
 pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary="ffmpeg.exe;." --recursive-copy-metadata "openai-whisper" 123.py


this is what i get as an error when i run the exe file that comes out
enter image description here
can someone help me figure out what's missing?

don't use images. just put verbatim output here.
